# How to Copy to Clipboard in JavaScript and make it HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I found some nice solutions here on how to copy text in JavaScript to the clipboard in:
[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)

But is there any way to give it a type? Want I want is to paste to clipboard something like:

this is < b >bold< /b >

and when pasting it into OpenOffice or Word, get

this is **bold**

Comment: are you copying "rendered HTML"? or "some plain text of HTML code"?

Comment: I'm copying html-code as text into the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You could just manipulate the string the user selects before sending it to the clipboard. Refer the answer for this question [which shows how a string manipulation could be done before copying it to the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584479/manipulating-the-clipboard-with-javascript-breaks-formatting).