# ZeroClipboard - formatting clipboard data to be bold or have certain font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I'm using a fairly standard ZeroClipboard setup. All vars are declared previously. `text` is the raw html.

```
zc = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
text = text.replace(/<\/p>/g, "\r");   // Preserve newline
text = $(text).text();                 // Strip html tags from text

zc.glue("export_results", "expage");   // This works fine
zc.setText(text);
```

As you can see, I'm using `replace` to translate the newline from `</p>` (end of paragraph) to `\r`.  I want to do something equivalent to mark text as bold or to be of a certain font size.

There's a bunch of posts on SO that skirt around the issue (e.g., [this one with a dead link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067894/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript-and-make-it-html)), but none with a solid answer. Is it possible? How is this information stored in the clipboard data?

Thanks.